# Convert IOS emoji to web or android emoji code

Tags: php, android, ios, web-services, unicode

I have been looking for the solution to this issue for 3 days but still not done.

I have a website, android app and iOS app... when I use emoji from web or android app it display the emoji properly (i am using BLOB dataType) but when I submit the same form from iOS app, it display emoji on iOS app only but on web and Android app, it shows the Unicode like `\ud83d\ude0d`.

I just want to show emoji on all devices even form is submitted from iOS or web or android app...

Comment: @Hashir First coordinated with the backend team to check backend database support emoji or not

Comment: @VikashKumar sir how can I check whether backend support emoji or not... ??? I am using blob datatype and emojis and showing on website and android as well...

Comment: @ Muhammad Hashir Anwaar can your share code.

Comment: @vikashkumar i have no code for thaat bcz... using BLOB datatype is showing emoji on web and android app...but ios app is making trouble...i want to convert ios emoji to web emoji code...

Answer (score 0):

That's from swift documentation:

```
let dollarSign = "\u{24}"        // $,  Unicode scalar U+0024
let blackHeart = "\u{2665}"      // ♥,  Unicode scalar U+2665
let sparklingHeart = "\u{1F496}" // , Unicode scalar U+1F496
```